# Load winform from class library from string

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection, class-library

Basically i have a class library that contains a lot of 'toolkit' for various applications i have written, i then usually reference this class library then create a blank winforms application and alter the program.cs to create a instance of the toolkit required. what im trying to do is create a single exe that can run all toolkit depending on a parameter or a settings xml file (this bit isn't the problem) the problem is creating an instance of a class from a different library from a string. what im asking is, is this possible? what ive tried so far:

```
    [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Advent.GlobalSettings.TestEnvironment = false;

            string namespaceName = "GlobalLib.Toolkits.XmlService.Main";
//first attempt
            Assembly ass = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            Type CAType = ass.GetType(namespaceName);
            var myObj = Activator.CreateInstance(CAType);
            Form nextForm2 = (Form)myObj;

//second attempt
            var t = Assembly
               .GetExecutingAssembly()
               .GetReferencedAssemblies()
               .Select(x => Assembly.Load(x))
               .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes()).First(x => x.FullName == namespaceName);

            var myObj2 = Activator.CreateInstance(t);

            Application.Run((Form) myObj2);

        }
```

First Attempt returns `Value cannot be null.` at `var myObj = Activator.CreateInstance(CAType);`
and second attempt returns `Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.`

Comment: What is the name of your form class? Is it "Main"?

Comment: Yes it is "Main" namespace 'GlobalLib.Toolkits.XmlService{public partial class Main : Form{ ...' bare in mind this is a reference library

Comment: You can try `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` instead of `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()`. This will give you all assembly currently loaded into the appdomain. But the exception of your second attempt gives you information about why the type cannot be instantiated, have a look at what it says.

Comment: @Houlahan: In your first attempt ass.GetType() returns null, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0cd10tb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for `Assembly.GetType` has a note on it saying:

> To search other assemblies for a type, use the Type.GetType(String) method overload, which can optionally include an assembly display name as part of the type name.

As the type you are trying to load is in a different assembly you should switch to `Type.GetType(String)` as suggested there. You will also need to adjust your `namespaceName` variable to include the assembly name in the format

```
"namespace.class, assemblyname"
```

Your code would then need to be something like this:

```
//I've had a stab in the dark at your assembly name
//the bit after the comma could be wrong
string namespaceName = "GlobalLib.Toolkits.XmlService.Main, GlobalLib.Toolkits";

Type CAType = Type.GetType(namespaceName);
var myObj = Activator.CreateInstance(CAType);
Form nextForm2 = (Form)myObj;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the classic dependency injection issue. However, if you want to skip a dependency injection container overhead you might mimic a behavior [MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has, which is load references from a folder. Going for `GetReferencedAssemblies()` is a bad idea in my opinion since it also searches all referenced .NET assemblies too, System, System.Windows.Forms, etc...

```
      string companyFolder = @"<folder with assemblies>";
      string fullClassName= @"<desired form fully qualified type name>";
      var di = new DirectoryInfo(companyFolder);
      // include forms in form apps too
      var referenceAssemblyFiles = di.GetFiles("*.dll").Union(di.GetFiles("*.exe")); 
      var types = referenceAssemblyFiles
        .Select(x => Assembly.LoadFile(x.FullName))
        .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
        .ToList();
      // might also check respective type is a form
      var t = types.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FullName == fullClassName);
      object myFormObj = null;
      if (t != null)
      {
        myFormObj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
        Application.Run((Form)myFormObj);
      }
```